# Set environment variable of php

Tags: php, environment-variables

I want to set the environment variable for php, whan I am doing is this

define variable php and give it this path:

```
C:\AppServ\php5
```

and edit the path variable to be like this

```
 E:\app\Dev.Alaa\product\11.1.0\db_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;%php%\php.exe
```

but when I run `php -v` from the cmd this error occurs:
`php_mvstring.ddl is missing` and then the command shows extra errors!!

I modify on php.ini-dist and on php.ini-recommended and activate these two lines

```
extension=php_exif.dll

extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

but the problem remains!!!

[image]

Comment: Have you check the existence of C:\AppServ\php5\ext\php_exif.dll file?

Comment: both php_exif.dll and php_mbstring.dll are exist !

Comment: Try putting the exact (i.e. C:\AppServ\php5\php.exe) path instead of %php%\php.exe

Comment: your problem could be related to the space in `Broadcom 802.11`

Answer (score 0):

It wroks, I have to go to winodows\php.ini and uncomment  these two lines

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

and be sure that php_mbstring.dll includes before php_exif.dll